# Is the set of states of an infinite dimensional unital $C^*$-algebra non-compact in the norm topology?

Tags: functional-analysis, dual-spaces

Let $\mathfrak{A}$ be an infinite dimensional unital $C^*$-algebra. I know that the ball $B_{1}$ of radius one  in the dual space $\mathfrak{A}^*$ is non-compact in the norm topology, but what about the set of states $E_\mathfrak{A}\subset B_{1}$ on $\mathfrak{A}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can write each linear functional in $B_1$ as a linear combination of four states, with all coefficients in the closed unit disk. It follows that  if $E_{\mathfrak A}$ is compact, so is $B_1$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I am not quite sure that I undestood it correctly. I see that the Jordan decomposition implies that every linear functional $\rho$ in $B_1$ can be written as $\rho=a_1\rho_1-a_2\rho_2+i(a_3\rho_3-a_4\rho_4)$, where $0\leq a_i\leq1$, and $\rho_i$ are states. But what is the next step? I would guess that given a sequence in $B_1$, if $E_\mathfrak{A}$ is compact and the $a_i's$ are bounded, by the above decomposition it is possible to find a convergent subsequence, is it correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly. You find a subsequence for the rider coefficient, the for the first state, and so on eight times.

Comment: I guess you understood what I said in spite of the typos :)

Comment: Yes :) thanks for the answer.